# Slider ( panel which is stored in a different file ) is no longer working properly after splitting it up

Tags: javascript, php, css

Being a noob in javascript, I've only edited a code - it's a different one from the other post I made, but this one might be easier to solve ( got no idea though ). It works when I put it on the same file, but the moment I try to include it, as a file, it no longer works propperly. I can open the panel, and it works. But it won't change Open Panel to Close Panel, and clicking Open Panel no longer does anything when it's already opened. Here's the code:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login_panel/css/slide.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PNG FIX for IE6 -->
    <!-- http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6 -->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login_panel/js/pngfix/supersleight-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="login_panel/js/slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toppanel">
    <div id="panel">
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <h1>Southland-Roleplay</h1>
                <h2>Member area</h2>        
                <p class="grey">Thank you for playing at Southland-Roleplay!</p>
                <h2>Credits go to:</h2>
                <p class="grey">Web Creation for the CSS / Bootstrap, Python and Calabresi for everything else.</p>
            </div>


            <?php

            if(!$_SESSION['id']):

            ?>



            <?php

            else:

            ?>
            <div class="left">
                <!-- Important Messages -->
                <form class="clearfix" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Important Messages</h1>
                    <?php
echo '<h1>WIP</h1>';
echo 'The UCP is still in progress. Dont expect all too much.<br><br>';

echo '<h1>Thank you!</h1>';
echo 'Thank you for using the UCP, and thank you for testing it!';
                    ?>
            </div>

            <div class="left">

            <h1>Members panel</h1>

            <p>Links:</p>
            UCP: <a href="ucp.php">Click me</a><br>
            Forums: <a href="http://www.forum.southland-roleplay.com/">Click me</a>
            <p>- or -</p>
            <a href="index.php?logoff">Log off</a>

            </div>

            <div class="left right">
            </div>

            <?php
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /login -->  

    <!-- The tab on top --> 
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="login">
            <li class="left">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['usr'] ? $_SESSION['usr'] : 'Guest';?>!</li>
            <li class="sep">|</li>
            <li id="toggle">
                <a id="open" class="open" href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['id']?'Open Panel':'';?></a>
                <a id="close" style="display: none;" class="close" href="#">Close Panel</a>         
            </li>
            <li class="right">&nbsp;</li>
        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- / top -->

</div> <!--panel -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

All I did was inclide it. but it no longer switched to close panel. Is there anything I've to re-define to make it work on every page I include it on?

Edit for @Pete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Expand Panel
    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");

    }); 

    // Collapse Panel
    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow"); 
    });     

    // Switch buttons from "Log In | Register" to "Close Panel" on click
    $("#toggle a").click(function () {
        $("#toggle a").toggle();
    });     

});
```

Comment: It slides down correctly, it only doesn't go back up. ( Tried the slash, no success )

Comment: Edited it in for you. See the original post.

Comment: It works when it's on the same page, but I can't get it to work when it's on a different page and included.